# Cannot require a file in Symfony from google-api-php-client

Tags: php, symfony, google-api

I need to use google-api-php-client.To do so, I added Google's github repository to my composer.json

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "google/google-api-php-client",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "type": "git",
                    "url": "https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "autoload" :{
                    "classmap": ["src"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

...

```
"require" : {
...
        "google/google-api-php-client": "dev-master"
}
```

Everything is installed properly and I have the following directory structure:

```
/vendor
  /google
    /google-api-php-client
      /examples
      /src
        /Google
          Client.php
```

When I create an object in my Controller, doing the following :

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
```

The path and the class are found. However, I get the following error :

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: require_once(Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/etienne/Developpement/Ima-Tech/Clients/lesoptions/vendor/google/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php line 18
```

In my Client.php file, I have the following at the beginning of the file:

```
require_once 'Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php';
```

If I change the line to :

```
require_once 'Auth/AssertionCredentials.php';
```

everything works fine for that inclusion. However, I don't want to change each `require_once` in every file of the google-api-php-client project. I'm sure there is a way to change the inclusion path or something therefore I'm wondering how can I tell that the namespace "Google" is the current directory ?

**Edit 1 :** I'm guessing that this may be caused because this project (google-api-php-client) does not use namespaces...

Comment: So the google-api-php-client bundle itself use broken paths?

Comment: how did you install the library? how does your `composer.json`'s autoload section look ?

Comment: @nifr I added the part you asked for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because the google-api-php-client does not use namespace...

Comment: @CoachNono it's not a namespace issue; it's because of a missing include path (see my answer below)

Comment: Can you post the full code, because i tried to add in repositories "autoload" :{"classmap": ["vendor/google/apiclient/src"]} and it is still not working for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following composer settings:

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client"
  }
],
...
"require": {
  "google/apiclient": "dev-master"
}
```

Notice I'm using `google/apiclient` instead of `google/google-api-php-client`. This seems to work fine for me. I'm on PHP 5.4.

I think the reason it's not working for you is because you're missing the `include-path` in your repository definition. If you look at the library's [composer.json](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/composer.json), you'll see the `include-path` pointing to the `src` dir.

Comment: Can you post the full code, because i tried to add in repositories "autoload" :{"classmap": ["vendor/google/apiclient/src"]} and it is  still not working for me. Thanks !